# How quickly does remineralization of teeth happen from brushing?

Tags: dentistry, research, bacteria

To the extent that toothpaste can remineralize tooth enamel, how quickly does it happen?

Is it a as-soon-as-there's-contact occurrence? Is it after ~30-120 seconds of scrubbing? Is it 10+ minutes after fluoride-laden toothpaste has remained undisturbed on the tooth/enamel surface?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?